# Velocity.js default values

Tags: javascript, velocity.js

I'm trying to modify the default option values for Velocity.js. - http://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity

The instructions say: "Option defaults can be globally overriden by modifying $.Velocity.defaults" so I've tried the following:

```
$.Velocity.defaults ({
    delay: 1000,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
```

but that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code tries to call the function `$.Velocity.defaults` with the argument

```
{
    delay: 1000,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
}
```

Since `$.Velocity.defaults` is an object, javascript can't call it: `TypeError: $.Velocity.defaults is not a function`. Instead, you could assign a new value:

```
$.Velocity.defaults = {
    delay: 1000,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
}
```

However, that overrides all the options, even the ones not specified. In order to modify individual properties, you can do this:

```
$.Velocity.defaults.delay = 1000;
$.Velocity.defaults.duration = 1000;
$.Velocity.defaults.easing = 'easeInOutBack';
```